# Travis CI reports linker errors for gcc-7 for a Vulkan project

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I have a problem with my CMake + conan setup which causes linker errors in Travis CI:

https://travis-ci.org/github/inexorgame/vulkan-renderer/builds/674840008

There are a lot of undefined references which means that the linker can't find the library files somehow. It can't find spdlog so the linker error is not Vulkan specific.

My `conanfile.py`setup looks like this:

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake

class InexorConan(ConanFile):

    settings = (
        "os",
        "compiler",
        "build_type",
        "arch"
    )

    requires = (
        "benchmark/1.5.0",
        "glm/0.9.9.7",
        "gtest/1.10.0",
        "spdlog/1.5.0",
        "glfw/3.3.2@bincrafters/stable",
        "toml11/3.1.0",
        "imgui/1.75",
        "stb/20200203",
        "nlohmann_json/3.7.3",
    )

    generators = "cmake"

    def imports(self):
        # Copies all dll files from packages bin folder to my "bin" folder (win)
        self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", src="bin")
        # Copies all dylib files from packages lib folder to my "lib" folder (macosx)
        self.copy("*.dylib*", dst="lib", src="lib") # From lib to lib
        # Copies all so files from packages lib folder to my "lib" folder (linux)
        self.copy("*.so*", dst="lib", src="lib") # From lib to lib

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

project(inexor-vulkan-renderer)

file(
    GLOB_RECURSE source_files
    "src/*.hpp"
    "src/*.cpp"
    "tests/*.*"
    "benchmarks/*.*"
)

# Use the folder structure in source code directory as project structure in Visual Studio.
function(assign_source_group)
    foreach (source_files IN ITEMS ${ARGN})
        if (IS_ABSOLUTE "${source_files}")
            file(RELATIVE_PATH _source_rel "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${source_files}")
        else ()
            set(_source_rel "${source_files}")
        endif ()
        get_filename_component(_source_path "${_source_rel}" PATH)
        string(REPLACE "/" "\\" _source_path_msvc "${_source_path}")
        source_group("${_source_path_msvc}" FILES "${source_files}")
    endforeach ()
endfunction(assign_source_group)

set(NORMAL_SOURCE_FILES)
set(TEST_SOURCE_FILES)
set(BENCHMARK_SOURCE_FILES)

# Sort source files by tests and benchmarks.
foreach (file ${source_files})
    if (file MATCHES ".*_test.*")
        set(TEST_SOURCE_FILES ${TEST_SOURCE_FILES} ${file})
    elseif (file MATCHES ".*_benchmark.*")
        set(BENCHMARK_SOURCE_FILES ${BENCHMARK_SOURCE_FILES} ${file})
    else ()
        set(NORMAL_SOURCE_FILES ${NORMAL_SOURCE_FILES} ${file})
    endif ()
endforeach ()

if (NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 3.7.0)
    message(STATUS "Using module to find Vulkan")
    find_package(Vulkan)
endif ()

# Dependency setup via conan.
# Download conan executer in case it does not exists.
if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
    message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
    file(
        DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/v0.14/conan.cmake"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake"
    )
endif ()

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)

conan_check(VERSION 1.19.1 REQUIRED)

conan_cmake_run(
    CONANFILE conanfile.py
    BASIC_SETUP
    BUILD outdated
    PROFILE default
    PROFILE_AUTO build_type
    KEEP_RPATHS
)

# Use the folder structure in source code directory as project structure in Visual Studio.
assign_source_group(${NORMAL_SOURCE_FILES})
assign_source_group(${TEST_SOURCE_FILES})
assign_source_group(${BENCHMARK_SOURCE_FILES})

add_executable(inexor-vulkan-renderer src/main.cpp ${NORMAL_SOURCE_FILES})
conan_target_link_libraries(inexor-vulkan-renderer)
target_compile_features(inexor-vulkan-renderer PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

target_include_directories(inexor-vulkan-renderer PRIVATE Vulkan::Vulkan)
target_link_libraries(inexor-vulkan-renderer Vulkan::Vulkan fmt spdlog)

# Use multiple threads to generate code.
if (MSVC)
    target_compile_options(inexor-vulkan-renderer PRIVATE "/MP")
endif ()

# Use root folder of the repository as working directory in Visual Studio debugger!
# Otherwise Visual Studio can't find any files like shaders or textures.
if (WIN32)
    set_property(TARGET inexor-vulkan-renderer PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
endif ()

file(
    GLOB_RECURSE NORMAL_SOURCE_FILES_WITHOUT_MAIN
    "src/vulkan-renderer/*"
)

add_executable(inexor-vulkan-renderer-tests ${NORMAL_SOURCE_FILES_WITHOUT_MAIN} ${TEST_SOURCE_FILES})
conan_target_link_libraries(inexor-vulkan-renderer-tests)
target_compile_features(inexor-vulkan-renderer-tests PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

target_include_directories(inexor-vulkan-renderer-tests PRIVATE Vulkan::Vulkan)
target_link_libraries(inexor-vulkan-renderer-tests Vulkan::Vulkan spdlog)

# Use root folder of the repository as working directory in Visual Studio debugger!
# Otherwise Visual Studio can't find any files like shaders or textures.
if (WIN32)
    set_property(TARGET inexor-vulkan-renderer PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
endif ()

if (MSVC)
    # Use multiple threads to compile the code.
    target_compile_options(inexor-vulkan-renderer-tests PRIVATE "/MP")
endif ()

add_executable(inexor-vulkan-renderer-benchmarks ${NORMAL_SOURCE_FILES_WITHOUT_MAIN} ${BENCHMARK_SOURCE_FILES})
conan_target_link_libraries(inexor-vulkan-renderer-benchmarks Vulkan::Vulkan spdlog)
target_compile_features(inexor-vulkan-renderer-benchmarks PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
target_include_directories(inexor-vulkan-renderer-benchmarks PRIVATE Vulkan::Vulkan)

target_include_directories(inexor-vulkan-renderer-benchmarks PRIVATE Vulkan::Vulkan)
target_link_libraries(inexor-vulkan-renderer-benchmarks spdlog gtest)

if (WIN32)
    set_property(TARGET inexor-vulkan-renderer-benchmarks PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
endif ()

# Use multiple threads to compile the code.
if (MSVC)
    target_compile_options(inexor-vulkan-renderer-benchmarks PRIVATE "/MP")
endif ()
```

This setup works for Visual Studio 2019.
Maybe conan can't pass the libraries to the target?

```
conan_target_link_libraries(inexor-vulkan-renderer-tests)
target_link_libraries(inexor-vulkan-renderer-tests Vulkan::Vulkan spdlog)
```

This is my Travis setup:

```
os: linux
language: python
python: "3.7"
dist: xenial

os: linux
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-7

before_script:
  - sudo apt-get install
  - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
  - sudo apt-get update -qq

install:
  - pip install conan
  - conan user
  - sudo apt-get install -qq g++-7
  - wget https://github.com/premake/premake-core/releases/download/v5.0.0-alpha11/premake-5.0.0-alpha11-linux.tar.gz?Human=true -O premake-5.0.0-alpha11-linux.tar.gz
  - tar -xzvf premake-5.0.0-alpha11-linux.tar.gz
  - sudo apt-get -qq update
  - sudo apt-get install -y libassimp-dev libglm-dev graphviz libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-present0 libpciaccess0 cmake libpng-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libx11-dev libx11-xcb-dev libmirclient-dev libwayland-dev libxrandr-dev
  - export VK_VERSION=1.2.131.1
  - wget -O vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-$VK_VERSION.tar.gz https://sdk.lunarg.com/sdk/download/$VK_VERSION/linux/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-$VK_VERSION.tar.gz
  - tar zxf vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-$VK_VERSION.tar.gz
  - export VULKAN_SDK=$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/$VK_VERSION/x86_64

script:
  - export CC=gcc-7
  - export CXX=g++-7
  - conan remote add bincrafters https://api.bintray.com/conan/bincrafters/public-conan
  - conan install .
  - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
  - cmake --build . --target inexor-vulkan-renderer
  - ctest .

notifications:
  email:
    recipients:
      - info@inexor.org
    on_success: change
    on_failure: always
```

I've been trying to fix this for several days now.
I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hint.

Sincere regards
Johannes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that your linker is looking for `std::__cxx11::basic_string` which belongs to libstdc++11. However, your conan profile is using libstdc++, which is incompatible, you can see it at the beginning of your log.

You need to configure your conan profile using libstdc++11 instead:

```
conan profile update settings.compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 default
```

Further reading:

https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html - Step 5

https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_gcc_abi.html

Comment: Thank you very much! This leaves me only with this one: https://travis-ci.org/github/inexorgame/vulkan-renderer/builds/674904380 /home/travis/.conan/data/libx11/1.6.8/bincrafters/stable/package/ee7e8c22a4645bde16d8dacf89e8f5b242755c89/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `reallocarray@GLIBC_2.26'

Comment: Similar error. The package which you downloaded was built on Ubuntu artful 17.10, and it has a newer glibc version (2.26) than your current distro which is xenial 16.04. You have 2 options: update your travis using bionic 18.04, or building all packages from sources by adding --build, but it will takes hours. I prefer the first choice, so you can use GCC8 instead.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: As clarification, there is actually a warning there in the travis Job log line 622: `WARNING: GCC OLD ABI COMPATIBILITY` which causes the change in the conan profile `settings.compiler.libcxx` for backwards compatibility